# Android - Google Analytics Account validation

Tags: android, validation, google-analytics

I have an app where it is possible for the user to input the Google Analytics Tracking ID.

Is it somehow possible to validate if the Google Analytics Tracking ID they have specified is valid?

I import 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+' though gradle in Android Studio.

And I have code similar to:

```
String googleAnalyticsTrackingId = "USER_INPUTTED_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID";
GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(appContext);
Tracker tracker = analytics.newTracker(googleAnalyticsTrackingId);
```

Is it possible using the analytics or the tracker to see if the googleAnalyticsTrackingId is valid or any ideas how to validate it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's much safer to use the Account Management API: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/account-management?hl=en